# Calculating number of pixels in polygon using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon

How to calculate the number of pixels in a polygon, especially, when an image contains null-value pixels? I tried the function `ee.Reducer.countEvery()`, but it does not work.

```js
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-122.420654296875, 37.96148894979038],
      [-122.530517578125, 37.735934739135104],
      [-122.244873046875, 37.82276800453933],
      [-121.904296875, 37.87481898883636]]]);

// Load a Landsat 8 image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_044034_20140318');


var c=image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  geometry: geometry
  });

print(c);
```

Comment: what in case if we need to count the pixels of three different categories in classified image?
Like I followed the code above it worked and gave the total pixels in one count just. I want different categories pixels separately.

Answer (score 10):

You should use `ee.Reducer.count()` instead of `ee.Reducer.countEvery()`.

```js
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-122.420654296875, 37.96148894979038],
      [-122.530517578125, 37.735934739135104],
      [-122.244873046875, 37.82276800453933],
      [-121.904296875, 37.87481898883636]]]);

// Load a Landsat 8 image.
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_044034_20140318');

var c = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry
  });

print(c);
```

[image]

I tested the reducer in a raster with null values, and you get the count of pixels with non-null values only.

[image]

EDIT: If you need to count non-null and null pixels, you must unmask the image first (This command fills the null values in the image with zeros).

```js
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var image = ee.Image('users/XXXX/cover2014');
image = image.unmask();

Map.addLayer(image, {});

var c = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry
  });

print(c);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried ee.Reducer.count() but it only calculates non-null pixels. I want to calculate the number of all the pixels, both null and non-null pixels included. If you can help me with that it would be great.

Comment: You can't count with the reducer pixels that do not exist. To perform the count on both, null and non-null pixels, you must use unmask() command first. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: I tried your answer. It is correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, if it was useful you could accept the answer.